# In MySQL Server 5.7 on Windows 10, update is not working remotely

Tags: mysql, spring

I am using a spring mapper to send an update query from my web app to the sql server.  I am able to send a `SELECT` statement and receive the correct response from my DB.  When I send an `UPDATE` statement, I can see the query pop up in the client connections section of MySQL Workbench, but the update does not happen.  When I copy and paste the same query (from the info of the query displayed in client connections) and run it from within MySQL workbench, the update succeeds.  I am using the same root user and password for both.  The web app is running on localhost.  My root user has all the permissions.  I have tried several things I have seen on this site and nothing seems to work.  Does anyone have any idea of what I should try next?  Please let me know if more information is needed. 
[Here is the update showing up in workbench when I send it from the web app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H48ZL.png)

[Here is the mapper](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MWh5n.png)

UPDATE: I also am getting this error in the console.
`"Caused by: com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.MySQLTransactionRollbackException: Lock wait timeout exceeded; try restarting transaction."`

All the tips are saying to just kill the connections that are in trouble, but even when I do this error persists.  Something is happening that is causing a lock.  Any thoughts?

Comment: Show us the code as that is obviously where your issue is

Comment: @RiggsFolly I just posted pics.  I don't think it is the code itself though, the SELECT statements work.  And the UPDATE clearly gets to the DB, it just doesn't do anything when it gets there

Answer (score 0):

You have not defined the `parameterType` for update. Please define the parameter type as follows:

This is a Example:

```
<update id="updateUser" parameterType="User">
        UPDATE users SET
            firstName = #{firstName},
            lastName = #{lastName},
            email = #{email}
        WHERE ID = #{id}
    </update>
```

Refer: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/mybatis/mybatis_mapper_xml.htm and http://msdsalehi.blogspot.com/2012/05/how-t-send-multiple-parameters-to.html

Comment: ok I set the parameter type, it is still not working.  I do not believe this is a code issue.  I believe this is a mysql configuration issue.  I had id and current_hp set as parameters in mapper.java, so they were passed in correctly.  The update query is getting to the db in both cases, it just isn't changing anything.  (see my first image for reference)